# Consulta do último resultado de Alteração

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, pl-sql, sqldeveloper

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um relatório de entrada de romaneio de notas.
Uma das consultas que preciso buscar é a última alteração de preço de um determinado produto.
Preciso de uma ajuda para conseguir trazer a última alteração realizada no preço do produto no banco de dados. Mas não sei que comando posso usar para que o banco me traga apenas a última alteração.

```
  select max(ap.id),
       ap.produto,
       ap.data_hora,
       venda_atual
       programado_atual
       from alteracao_precos ap
where ap.carga = 'T'
   and ap.politica = 57
   and ap.tipo_venda = 1  
group by ap.produto,
ap.data_hora,
venda_atual,
programado_atual
order by ap.produto
```

Atualmente está dessa forma, mas preciso ver somente o último, tentei usar o MAX na data, mas ele repete os registros caso tenha mais de uma no mesmo dia.

Comment: Qual a estrutura de alteracao_precos ? Tem algo que "desempate" a data ?

Comment: Tem a opção de ID, mas por algum motivo ele também está repetindo resultados. Vou mostrar como está saindo o resultado.

Answer (score -4):

Deu certo, foi resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT ap.produto
                   ,ap.venda_atual
                   ,ap.programado_atual
                   ,ap.politica
                   --,ap.politica
               FROM alteracao_precos ap
               LEFT JOIN alteracao_precos ap2 ON ((ap2.politica  = ap.politica) AND
                                                 (ap2.produto   = ap.produto)   AND
                                                 (ap2.data_hora > ap.data_hora))
             WHERE ap.carga = 'T'
               AND ap.politica = 57
               AND ap.tipo_venda = 1
               AND ap2.politica IS NULL
```

Foi realizado um alto relacionamento da tabela, e colocado a data sempre maior que a última.